# Arduino IDE does not display examples folder from my custom library

Tags: arduino-ide, library

I have created a custom library for local usage. I call is `ABC_node` for ESP32 and the structure is as follows:

```
.
|-- examples
|   |-- bnoCalibStorage
|   |   `-- bnoCalibStorage.ino
|   |-- influxHTTP_write
|   |   `-- influxHTTP_write.ino
|   |-- influxPing
|   |   `-- influxPing.ino
|   |-- influxUDP_write
|   |   `-- influxUDP_write.ino
|   `-- rtcTimestamp
|       `-- rtcTimestamp.ino
|-- keywords.txt
|-- library.properties
|-- README.md
|-- ABC_Node.cpp
`-- ABC_Node.h
```

I tried following the Adafruit GitHub Repository structure where each example is placed inside a folder named after the sketch.

I am hosting this repository on a private GitLab Server. I used `git tag v1.0.0` to create a tag and from GitLab I could download the `.zip` file for the stable v1.0.0 library.

I manually extracted the files to my `<user>\Documents\Arduino\libraries` folder and renamed the folder to `ABC_Node` (since my gitlab repo is named something else)

I restarted my IDE but I could not find the library `ABC_Node` in

```
Sketch\Include Library\
```

#### `library.properties`

```
name=ABC_Node
version=1.0.0
author=Shan Desai
maintainer=Shan Desai
sentence=Firmware to create InfluxDB measurements and send them via HTTP/UDP to Core
paragraph=ABC_Node provides `String` based InfluxDB measurements which can then be sent via HTTP/UDP to a central InfluxDB instance.
category=Data Processing, DAQ
architecture=ESP32
repository=https://[gitlab-address]/node-repo.git
```

I followed the [Libraries Guide from Arduino on local Installation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries)

#### System

Windows 10

Arduino IDE 1.8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your library.properties is lacking a line.  Emulating your library with blank files and copying in your library.properties content, and running on Linux from the command line, it reports to me:

```
Invalid library found in /home/matt/Arduino/libraries/ABC_Node: Missing 'url' from library
```

So you lack the line:

```
url=https://whatever.website.you.want.to/point.to
```

(Or use something like `http://example.com` if you don't want one...)

I put that line in, and magically the library appears in the list.

Comment: Can you tell me what commandline you used here ?

Comment: You just run the Arduino program. No need for any options or anything.

Comment: so just execute it from the IDE?

Comment: Pardon?  Execute what from the IDE? On Linux at a BASH terminal prompt I typed, precisely, `/home/matt/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/arduino` and it gave me that error on the screen as the IDE loaded.  I doubt you can do the same on Windows though...

Comment: That was what I was expecting as an answer. The commandline tool `arduino`. You are right it I am not sure if I can execute `arduino` on CMD or Powershell. Thanks.

Comment: You can run it from the command line, but whether it would give you any meaningful output on the command line is anyone's guess. You may want to run `java -jar <path/to/arduino/jar/file>` - you'll have to work out where the right jar file is though...